# Get the frequency of all combinations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the purchase frequency of all combinations of products.

Suppose my transactions are the following

```
userid    product
u1        A
u1        B
u1        C
u2        A
u2        C
```

So the solution should be

```
combination  count_of_distinct_users
A            2
B            1
C            2
A, B         1
A, C         2
B, C         1 
A, B, C      1
```

i.e 2 users have purchased product A, one users has purchased product B..., 2 users have purchased products A and C ...

Comment: And your attempt was....?

Comment: Please explain your logic.

Comment: But there are two users who have purchase A & B , then why cout is 1 ?

Comment: @R.Baraiya which two users have bought A & B? only u1 has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sefine a function `combine` to generate all combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations

def combine(s):
    result = []
    for i in range(1, len(s)+1):
        for c in list(combinations(s, i)):
            result+=[c]
    return result
```

This will give all combinations in a column:

```
df.groupby('user')['product'].apply(combine)
# Out: 
# user
# 1    [(A,), (B,), (C,), (A, B), (A, C), (B, C), (A,...
# 2                                 [(A,), (C,), (A, C)]
# Name: product, dtype: object
```

Now use [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df.groupby('user')['product'].apply(combine).reset_index(name='product_combos') \
  .explode('product_combos').groupby('product_combos') \
  .size().reset_index(name='user_count')
# Out: 
#   product_combos  user_count
# 0           (A,)           2
# 1         (A, B)           1
# 2      (A, B, C)           1
# 3         (A, C)           2
# 4           (B,)           1
# 5         (B, C)           1
# 6           (C,)           2
```

Careful with the combinations because the list gets large with many different products!

Answer (score 2):

Here my simple trick is to convert df to dict with list of users like **{'A':[u1, u2], 'B':[u1]}** then find the combination and merge both products list of users total. like **A:[u1, u2] and B:[u1]** so merge will be **[2,1]** and last took the min value pf that list so final count output will be **1**.

Code:

```
from more_itertools import powerset

d = df.groupby('product')['user'].apply(list).to_dict()
##output: {'A': ['u2', 'u1'], 'B': ['u1'], 'C': ['u1', 'u2']}


new= pd.DataFrame([', '.join(i) for i in list(powerset(d.keys()))[1:]], columns =['users'])
## Output: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A, B', 'A, C', 'B, C', 'A, B, C']


new['count'] = new['users'].apply(lambda x: min([len(d[y]) for y in x.split(', ')]))
new
```

Output:

```
users       count
0   A           2
1   B           1
2   C           2
3   A, B        1
4   A, C        2
5   B, C        1
6   A, B, C     1
```